# Using AMPL C++ Apis for C?

Tags: c, ampl

I've looked for C APIs, but I've only found C++ API's that can't be used inside a C code.

Are there any C (not C++ or C#) APIs or another way for using AMPL in a C code?

Comment: This question may be liable to downvotes as poor grammar is not recommended in this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There being no C API for AMPL as far as I can tell, your best bet is to write C++ wrappers for the tasks you want to perform, assigning them C linkage (`extern "C"`) and building them with a C++ compiler.  Done correctly, these will be callable from C code.  The C code will not be able to handle AMPL objects directly, however, so your wrappers will need to perform some kind of data marshaling in both directions.

I do recommend wrappers specific to your particular tasks, as opposed to generic wrappers for the whole API.  I suspect that you would find the latter a much larger and more difficult task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think is better to use another language supported directly by AMPL apis.

Comment: As you like, @Adl.  I had supposed you were asking about C because you wanted to integrate AMPL with an existing C codebase.  If you're starting from scratch and AMPL integration is a key requirement then I certainly agree that choosing a language with direct AMPL support is probably a better strategy.